# absolute is not available for the grandchildren of flex elements?

Tags: css

How do I get the `.top_box` to be fixed in the head of the `.content`?

With the current code, the `.top_box` always scrolls along with the `.content`.

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 160px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.title_container {
    background: pink;
}
.content {
    height: 0;
    flex: auto;
    position: relative;

    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: bisque;
}
.top_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 16px;
    background: royalblue;
}

.scroll_fill {
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title_container">anyString</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="top_box"></div>
        <div class="scroll_fill"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 160px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.title_container {
    background: pink;
}
.content {
    height: 0;
    flex: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: bisque;
}
.contentInner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.top_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 16px;
    background: royalblue;
}
.scroll_fill {
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title_container">anyString</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="top_box"></div>
        <div class="contentInner">
            <div class="scroll_fill"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the order of the HTML-Elements in the code and write `.top` before `.item`. If you do that, you can also remove most of the CSS because it’s unnecessary.

**Here‘s a full example:**

```css
.box1 {
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.box2 {
    background: pink;
}
.box3 {
    background-color: red;
}
.top {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: blue;
}
.item {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box2">anyString</div>
    <div class="box3">
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also a few other things: I wouldnt recommend just using `divs` and naming them like *box1, box2, box3, ...*. Instead, give them names wich describe their use and meaning like *wrapper, top_container, bottom_container, top_item, content, ...*:
[CSS Naming Conventions](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-naming-conventions-that-will-save-you-hours-of-debugging-35cea737d849/amp/).

You can also use specific tags with semantic meanings: [Sematic HTML5 Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)

Hope that helps